# Code folding (regions) in VS and Netbeans

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, netbeans, region, folding

I'm currently working on a javascript project with another programmer.
I use Visual Studio and he uses Netbeans.

We encountered a problem when using code folding on our code:

VS is supporting this syntax:

```
// #region Name
   Code...
// #endregion
```

but Netbeans supports this syntax:

```
// <editor-fold>
   Code...
// </editor-fold>
```

Is there one syntax that can work for both of us? Is there a way to make one of the editors to support the other syntax?